# How to post a long string containing XML to Web API

Tags: c#, xml, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to post a long string (containing XML) to my Web API controller, but I'm failing miserablely.

The following works if TextAsXml is short, but when TextAsXml is long it fails "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.", which is understandable.

```
// Client code
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var requestUri = "http://localhost:49528/api/some";
  var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
  {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Author", "John Doe"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TextAsXml", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>")
  });

  var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

// Controller code
public HttpResponseMessage Post(SomeModel someModel)
{
  // ...
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

public class SomeModel
{
  public string Author { get; set; }
  public string TextAsXml { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get the above code to work when TextAsXml is long? I tried playing around with StringContent and MultipartContent, but couldn't get it to work.

```
// This results in 500 Internal server error.
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var requestUri = "http://localhost:49528/api/some";
  var textAsXml = File.ReadAllText("Note.xml");
  var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
  content.Add(new StringContent("John Doe"), "Author");
  content.Add(new StringContent(textAsXml), "TextAsXml");

  var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the XML as content without Uri encoding.

Comment: That part I already figured out :-) But how? As you can see in my example that results in 500 Internal Server Error, I'm calling PostAsync with a MultipartFormDataContent with no luck.